# How can I translate content from quizapi.io into other languages?

Tags: php, laravel, translation

on laravel 10 site I need to fill my questions database from https://quizapi.io/docs/1.0/overview API,
but with English content I also need text in Spain and Ukraine
Seems this service provides data only in english. How can translate these content into Spain and Ukraine?
later maybe I will need to add other languages...

Comment: Probably need to find a translation API an pass the English through that

Comment: https://translated.com/translation-api?refid=5605&sem_ad=638501688658&sem_kw=api%20translation&sem_pos=&utm_campaign=SRC+English+EU&utm_source=Gads&utm_term=api%20translation&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_mt=p&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ad=638501688658&hsa_src=g&hsa_cam=20406902761&hsa_kw=api%20translation&hsa_grp=150429088214&hsa_tgt=kwd-389013835637&hsa_ver=3&hsa_acc=6606703650&gad_source=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI25KGtZ-ZhAMVYo2DBx373AWUEAAYASAAEgIJsfD_BwE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking trough the documentation of quizapi it sadly doesnt have the option to give the data in a different locale.

Using a translation api could be the way to go, but it could lead to answers not being fully correct and questions lacking the right grammar.

The google translate API has an free tier, you can check it out at:

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest

Comment: This https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php package ?

Comment: That isnt an official package released by google, would not recommend using it...